# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Intel Graphics Issue

Tags: drivers, graphics, mouse, 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a machine that used to run 16.04 LTS with no issue.  However, now randomly, the system will leave a trail of mouse arrows around when I move the mouse which keep "moving" from the original start position to wherever I move the mouse.  Any advice on possible fixing this issue?  Should I file a bug for this?

Processor: Celeron CPU N2050 @ 1.6 Ghz x 2
Graphics: Intel HD Garphics 400 (Braswell)
Memory 3.8 GiB

Comment: Try switching to Xorg as described here: askubuntu.com/questions/966651/mouse-lagging-on-ubuntu-17-10